# Why is the Wireless option not visible for Display Sharing?

Tags: windows-10, display

I"m trying to extend my Windows 10 display to a second Windows 10 laptop per [these instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/359471/how-to-use-a-windows-laptop-or-tablet-as-a-wireless-monitor/#comments).

However, the instructions say I should see a ..wireless option :
[image]

But I do not see it on my screen:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I do not see it on my screen:

The lack of the option indicates your device does not meet the requirements to support Miracast.

> Both devices (the sender and the receiver) need to be Miracast certified for the technology to work.

Source: [Miracast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast#Windows)

> In order to take advantage of this trick, you’ll need two Windows 10 machines that support the Miracast streaming video standard. Most newer laptops and tablets have this built in, as do some desktops. However, if you’ve built your own desktop, or have one that doesn’t have a Wi-Fi adapter, it might not support Miracast.

Source: [How to Use a Windows Laptop as a Wireless Monitor (for Another PC)](https://www.howtogeek.com/359471/how-to-use-a-windows-laptop-or-tablet-as-a-wireless-monitor/#comments)

You should verify that your device actually supports Miracast and you are not getting the following message.

[image]

> If you’re not sure whether or not your Windows laptop or tablet supports Miracast, click the Start button, type “Projecting” into the search box, and then click the “Projecting to this PC” result. If the settings menu says “This device doesn’t support receiving Miracast,” then you won’t be able to use it as a wireless monitor.